# Conocer Estado de CheckBox en Form no propietario

Tags: c++

Intento conocer el estado de varios CheckBox de otra aplicación y en función de ellos aplicar criterios en mi programa. Los checBox no tienen Titulo, solo Clase y es Button.
Puedo localizarlos por su ubicación en el form. Pero como llego a su valor?
Este es el Callback de pruebas.
**EDITO:**
No había puesto el EnumChildWindows.
El conocer su estado buscando el color, sería posible,pero me parece poco "elegante".
Conocéis como llegar al valor?

```
static BOOL CALLBACK enumWindowCallback(HWND hwnd_Enum, LPARAM lparam_Enum)
{
    TITLEBARINFO TitleInfo;
    TitleInfo.cbSize = sizeof(TITLEBARINFO);
    int length = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd_Enum);
    char* buffer = new char[length + 1];
    GetWindowTextA(hwnd_Enum, buffer, length + 1);
    std::string windowTitle(buffer);
    TCHAR windowClase[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR winClasBase[7] = { L'B','u' ,'t', 't','o','n' };
    int clasleng = GetClassName(hwnd_Enum, windowClase, 30);
    int visible = IsWindowVisible(hwnd_Enum);
    int iguales = not(_tcscmp(windowClase, winClasBase));
    if (visible && iguales) 
    {   printf("\n hwnd_Enum : %d  Window Title: ", hwnd_Enum);  printf("%s", buffer); printf(" Clase: "); _tprintf(L"%s\n", windowClase);
        BOOL resss = GetTitleBarInfo(hwnd_Enum,  &TitleInfo);
        Sleep(500);
    }
    delete[] buffer;
    return true;

//---------
void BuscaBoton() {
    HWND hwnd_1 = FindWindowW(L"pack", L"Display");
    if (hwnd_1) {
        EnumChildWindows(hwnd_1,enumWindowCallback, NULL);
    }
```